# Separable extension

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $A$ be an $R$-algebra, $B$ an $R$-subalgebra of $A$ and $I$ an
ideal of $A$. Kazuhiko Hirata and Kozo Sugano proved that: if $A$ is
a separable extension of $B$, then $A/I$ is a separable extension of
$B/(B\cap I)$. In what case is the converse true?